# VueJS 2 List Animation Not working as expected with transition name

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I've trying to build a list animation similar to in https://stripe.com/radar (Review flagged payments). Cards scrolling vertically, one by one. Each card is from an array.

I've implemented it and its working fine. However, the animation is not smooth. Looks like the animation name="animate" in transition-group is not working.

Tried everything as in the documentation. Couldn't find a solution

https://jsfiddle.net/0aLfzs9u/

```
<div class="container" id="vue-instance">
 <transition-group name="animate">
    <div class="row align-items-center quote" :class="{active: key==1 }" @click="items.pop()" v-for="(item,key) in items" :key="item">
      <div class="col-4 mt-3 mb-3">
        <p>{{item}} Cement</p>
        <small>75 bags</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
        <p>Thrissur</p>
        <small>12 hours ago</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition-group>
  <p>
  some footer content
  </p>
 </div>


    var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    items: [1,2,3]
  },
    created() {
    let self = this
    setInterval(function() {
      self.items.pop();
      self.items.splice(0, 0, Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1));
    }, 2000);
  }
});



.animate-enter-active,
.animate-leave-active{
  transition: all 2s;
  max-height: 230px;
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-enter,
.animate-leave-to{
  transition: all 2s;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.quote {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(.95);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.active {
  filter: blur(0px);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Does this fix your issue?
https://jsfiddle.net/0aLfzs9u/2/

Comment: I've tried that before. It's not a good solution. Because in mobile, height may change. Try decreasing the width, it collapses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself: https://jsfiddle.net/rfs12yh6/

```
<div id="list-complete-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <transition-group name="list-complete" tag="p">
    <h3
      v-for="(item,key) in items"
      v-bind:key="item"
      class="list-complete-item quote"
      :class={active:key!=1}
    >
      {{ item }}
    </h3>
  </transition-group>
  <p>Some footer</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#list-complete-demo',
  data: {
    items: [1,2,3],
    nextNum: 10
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function () {
        this.items.pop()
        this.items.splice(0, 0, this.nextNum++)
    }
  }
})

.list-complete-item {
  transition: all 1s;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.list-complete-enter
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.list-complete-leave-to
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
.list-complete-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
.quote{
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.active{
  filter: blur(1px);
  transition: all 1s ease
}
```